# C++ pointer address explanation

Tags: c++, pointers

I am new to C++ and I have a piece of code like this:

```
int firstvalue=10;
int * mypointer;
mypointer = &firstvalue;
cout << "pointer is " << *mypointer << '\n';
cout << "pointer is " << mypointer << '\n';
cout << "pointer is " << &mypointer << '\n';
```

The result is:

```
pointer is 10
pointer is 0x7ffff8073cb4
pointer is 0x7ffff8073cb8
```

Can anyone explain to me why the result of "mypointer" and "&mypointer" are different?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `mypointer` is a variable too, so it has its own address...

Answer (score 8):

- `mypointer` is the **value** of the variable `mypointer`. And that value is, due to your assignment, the address of `firstvalue`.
- `&mypointer` is the **address** of the variable `mypointer`. That is, the address of `mypointer`.

So, `mypointer` is the address of `firstvalue`, and `&mypointer` is the address of `mypointer`. Since `firstvalue` and `mypointer` are distinct variables, they have different addresses.

Answer (score 2):

See inscribed comments

```
int firstvalue=10; // first variable, stored at say location 2000, so &firstvalue is 2000
int * mypointer; // second variable, stored at say location 2004, so &mypointer is 2004
mypointer = &firstvalue; // mypointer had garbage, now has 2000
cout << "pointer is " << *mypointer << '\n'; // contents of mypointer i.e. firstvalue (10)
cout << "pointer is " << mypointer << '\n'; // value of mypointer i.e. 2000
cout << "pointer is " << &mypointer << '\n'; // address of mypointer i.e. 2004
```

got it?

Answer (score 1):

In the example, the & operator means "the address of". Therefore "mypointer" is the address of the value 10, but "&mypointer" is an address of an address whose value is 10.

Answer (score 1):

`firstvalue` is a variable which can hold an `int` type value. This variable has its own address `0x7ffff8073cb4`.

`myvariable` is a (pointer) variable that can hold the an `int *` type value, i.e address of a variable that can hold `int` type value. This variable has its own address `0x7ffff8073cb8`.

[image]